# Simple is parallel test

Tags: linear-algebra

**Please excuse if this is a very basic question but I'm really stuck.**

I'm starting to study linear algebra (using Fraleigh's book). One of its excercises is:

> Find all scalars $c$, if any exist, such that the vector $\vec{v}=\{c^2, c^3, c^4\}$ is parallel to the vector $\vec{w} = \{1,-2,4\}$ with the same direction.

Now, I understand that in order for $\vec{v}$ to be parallel with $\vec{w}$ then there must be an scalar $r$ such that $r$ $\vec{v} = \vec{w}$ and so:

$r\{c^2, c^3, c^4\}$ must be equal to $\{1,-2,4\}$.

But at this point I get stuck. How can I find the r that satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two vectors are equal precisely when their coordinates are equal. Thus, the vector
$$r\{c^2,c^3,c^4\}=\{rc^2,rc^3,rc^4\}$$
equals the vector $\{1,-2,4\}$ if and only if
$$rc^2=1\quad\text{and}\quad rc^3=-2\quad\text{and}\quad rc^4=4.$$
**Hint:** what do we know 
$$\frac{-2}{1}$$
would have to equal?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zev. However I don't understand where the -2/1 comes from. I mean, from the equations c = $\sqrt{1/r}$ and so on.. (third and fourth root).

Comment: No taking roots is necessary; just division. Look again at the equations we are assuming the numbers $r$ and $c$ satisfy.

Comment: I think I see your point. From the first eq. $c^2=1/r$, from the second one $r(1/r)c=-2$ and from the third one $r(1/r)(1/r)=4$ so $c^2 = 4$ and $c = -2$?

Comment: That's right, but you're overcomplicating it a bit: just take
$$c=\frac{rc^3}{rc^2}=\frac{-2}{1}=-2.$$
Now, you know that if there were any numbers $r$ and $c$ such that this were possible, we would in fact have to have $c=-2$. What does that mean $r$ would have to be?

Comment: Oh god! Now I see, I don't even need to operate... Just replacing as the first step will give the answer. Thanks for your nice way of getting me into discovering the answer :)

Comment: Glad to help!$\,$